# Completeness Axiom in Preference Relation

Tags: preferences

My textbook, ***Microeconomic Theory*** by *Mas-Colell, Whinston, and Green* states that given a preference relation $\succsim$ on $X$,

> **Strict preference relation** $\succ$ is defined by 
>   $ x \succ y \iff x \succsim y \text{ but not } y \succsim x $
>
> **Indifference relation** $\sim$ is defined by 
>   $ x \sim y \iff x \succsim y \text{ and } y \succsim x $
>
> **Completeness property**: For all $x,y \in X$, we have either $x \succsim y$ or $y \succsim x$ or both.

Suppose $\succsim$ on $X$ is complete. Define $A$ to be the truth set of $x \succsim y$, $B$ to be the truth set of $y \succsim x$.

Since $\succsim$ is complete, $A \cup B$ is the universal set.

First, $x \succ y \iff x \succsim y \land \lnot (y \succsim x)$, hence the truth set of $x \succ y$ is $A \setminus B$.

Next, $y \succ x \iff y \succsim x \land \lnot (x \succsim y)$, hence the truth set of $y \succ x$ is $B \setminus A$.

Finally, $x \sim y \iff x \succsim y \land y \succsim x$, hence the truth set of $x \sim y$ is $A \cap B$.

Using the identity $A \cup B = (A \setminus B) \sqcup (A \cap B) \sqcup (B \setminus A)$, is it safe to say that

> If $\succsim$ is complete, then for any $x,y \in X$ exactly one of $x \succ y$ or $x \sim y$ or $y \succ x$ holds.

Comment: Yes, that seems perfectly valid reasoning to me

Comment: This just applies the definitions of completeness and relations together. You don't need set theory to show this. You could just work from the mathematical definitions. Anyway...yeah...it is true.